# What is the solution of $yy'''+3y'y''=0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I tried to substitute:

$$y' =p , \quad y'' = p'p,\quad y''' = p''p^2 +(p')^2p
$$
where $y'=\dfrac{dy}{dt}$ and $p'=\dfrac{dp}{dy}$.

Now I have

$$y(p''p^2+(p')^2p) + 3p'p^2=0 \;\Rightarrow \; yp''p + y(p')^2+3p'=0.
$$

But I'm stuck here. I don't know how to continue.

Answer (score 1):

Multiply with $y^2$ to find
$$
(y^3y'')'=0.
$$
Next you can find
$$
y'^2+\frac{C}{y^2}=D
$$
After that it gets hairy.

Answer (score 0):

$$(yy’’)’=-2y’y’’$$
$$\implies{d(yy’’)\over dx}=-2y’{d(y’)\over dx}$$
$$\implies yy’’=-(y’)^2+c$$
$$\implies \frac {y’}y +\frac cy=-\frac{y’’}{y’}$$
See if you can finish it. (Some edge values may be beneficial)

Answer (score 0):

$$yy'''+3y'y''=0$$
You can also rexrite it as
$$\dfrac {y'''}{y''}=-3\dfrac {y'}{y}$$
$$(\ln y'')'=-3(\ln y)'$$
Integrate.
$$y''=\dfrac C {y^3}$$
$$y''y'=C\dfrac {y'} {y^3}$$
$$y'^2=\dfrac {C_1} {y^2}+C_2$$